# decidability and countability

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

The diagonolisation technique is utilized to prove that the halting problem is undecidable. However, I kind of sense that it is making the assumption that decidable sets should be countable. Is this true? If not, which part am I missing?

Comment: there are countably many algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original proof of the undecidability of the halting problem assumes that there exists a program that can determine whether any other program halts and then explicitly constructs a counterexample that the program will give the wrong answer for. No assumptions of countability are necessary for this. However, there are only countably many computable sets because there are only countably many programs of finite length.

Comment: Adding to this just a little bit. The countability aspect doesn't really come into play in the proof of the halting problem. The countability aspect follows from a few facts though. Strings of finite length are enumerable (for example, you can enumerate finite length binary strings). All Turing Machines can be represented as a finite length string, known as an encoding. It follows that there are countably many Turing Machines.